# GTM: Using transactionProducts Varible for Custom HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I'm using the Google Tag Manager (GTM) with E-Commerce-Tracking. The Shop-System sends the following information to the GTM:

```html
dataLayer = [{
"event":"transaction",
"transactionId":"100002486",
"transactionDate":"2015-09-03",
"transactionTotal":295,
"transactionShipping":0,
"transactionTax":26.82,
"transactionPaymentType":"Rechnung",
"transactionCurrency":"EUR",
"transactionShippingMethod":"tablerate",
"transactionProducts":[
{
"name":"Handelsvertretergesetz",
"sku":"9783700760344",
"category":"Buch",
"price":113.64,
"quantity":1
},
{
"name":"Steuerrecht",
"sku":"9783700759294",
"category":"Kodex",
"price":77.27,
"quantity":2
}
];
```

Analytics E-Commerce Tracking works perfectly. But now to the challange:

I need to implement another Non-Google E-Commerce-Tracking Code via the GTM which in end should look like this:

```js
ScarabQueue.push(['purchase', {
    orderId: '231213',
    items: [
      {item: '182', price: 19.9, quantity: 1},
      {item: '747', price: 29.7, quantity: 3}
    ]
}]);
```

So I thought I just add another Custom HTML Tag via the GTM:

```js
<script>
ScarabQueue.push(['purchase', {
    orderId: '{{transactionId}}',
    items: [
      {{transactionProducts}}
    ]
}]);
</script>
```

While the {{transactionId}} gets inserted correctly, the items are missing.

Any idea how to get the {{transactionProducts}} Variable into a Custom HTML Tag? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Eike, thanks for your reply. "transactionProducts" is already a GTM Variable.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not read that thoroughly - I usually do not do stupid comments :-(

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Can you clarify what you mean "get the {{transactionProducts}} variable into a Custom HTML tag? Maybe I'm taking it too literally, but just use "{{transactionProducts}}" where you need to?? Does your "ScarabQueue" object interact somehow with the GTM dataLayer to push the ecomm data?? If not, then may be that's why things are missing.

Comment: Hi nyuen, thanks for your reply. I hope I can clarify it a little bit: On the E-Commerce Confirmation Page is already a standard datalayer that pushes all E-Commerce information to the GTM, including the variables {{transactionId}} and {{transactionProducts}}. I'm already using these for Google Analytics and it works perfectly fine. The challenge is to implement another e-commerce-tracking tag (ScarabQueue) by using the GTM Variables which are already available. Since there is no tag template like for Google Analytics I have to use a custom HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem (or at least one problem). In your ScarabQueue "items" is supposed to be an object with two product data arrays. However you are pushing an object (and this object contains the product data arrays). I have a bit trouble with phrasing that correctly, so I include a screenshot what I mean:

[image]

On the left hand you see the correct (manual) assignment, on the right you see a push from you example dataLayer. Left hand items is an Object that contains 2 items (the arrays with the product data). Right hand "items" contains only one element (the transactionProducts object) that has the product data nested inside.

You might try to rename the {{transactionProducts}} variable to "items" and push that:

```
items = {{transactionProducts}};
ScarabQueue.push(['purchase', {
    orderId: '{{transactionId}}',
    items
}]);
```

No guarantees, but I think that should work, or at least it results in a similar structure to the "manual" data assignment:

[image]

Comment: Hi Eike, thanks for your suggestion! I gave it a try but now the JavaScript-Compiler from the GTM is giving the following error: "this language feature is only supported in es6 mode: extended object literals. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features."

Comment: That's weird - this is simple variable assignment. I forgot a semicolon after the first line, did you fix that (I fixed in my example) ? Else this might be what threw GTM off.